# ps -ef and top does not output a list of processes. What parameters should be increased?

Tags: solaris

I tried to execute `ps -ef` or `top` but they  does not output a list of processes and is waiting for something.
`vmstat 99% idle CPU`.

OS Solaris 8. Hardware Sun V440. 4 CPU 16 G RAM. Swap 4 Gb.

After several attempts to execute the command, I opened the session again.

The `ps -ef|wc -l`  command showed the result of 672, in the normal state of the 38-42 process in total. The server was rebooted.

What parameters should be increased in the kernel so that the server would work stably with a large number of processes?

```
 /etc/system

set rlim_fd_cur=1024
```

**update 1**
The problem was in a small number of file descriptors by default 1024.

```
set rlim_fd_max=4096
```

Comment: My recommendation - try to do analytic of running processes. Typically you have some repeated job which hangs and eats memory. Check your crontab and monitoring plugins [nagios, zabbix, etc].

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines in `/etc/system` and reboot

```
set pidmax=60000
set maxusers = 4096
set maxuprc = 50000
set max_nprocs = 50000
```

**pidmax** - Specifies value of largest possible process ID.
Valid for Solaris 8 and later releases. [Range from 266 to 999999, default 30000]

**maxusers** - The maximum number of processes on the system, The number of quota structures held in the system. The size of the directory name look-up cache (DNLC).[Range from 1 to 4096, default: lesser of the amount of memory in Mbytes and 2048]

**maxuprc** - Specifies the maximum number of processes that can be created on a system by any one user [Range from 1 to max_nprocs - reserved_procs, default max_nprocs - reserved_procs]

**reserved_procs** - Specifies number of system process slots to be reserved in the process table for processes with a UID of root (0). [Range from 5 to MAXINT, Default 5]

**max_nprocs** - Specifies the maximum number of processes that can be created on a system. Includes system processes and user processes. Any value specified in /etc/system is used in the computation of maxuprc. [Range from 266 to value of maxpid, default 10 + (16 x maxusers)]

See official Solaris 8 documentation about this params on [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/816-0607/816-0607.pdf).